# Procedural macro for retrieving data from a nested struct by index

Tags: rust, macros

I am trying to write a rust derive macro for retrieving data from a nested struct by index.  The struct only contains primitive types u8, i8, u16, i16, u32, i32, u64, i64, or other structs thereof.  I have an Enum which encapsulates the leaf field data in a common type which I call an Item().  I want the macro to create a .get() implementation which returns an item based on a u16 index.

Here is the desired behavior.

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, PartialOrd, Copy, Clone)]
pub enum Item {
    U8(u8),
    I8(i8),
    U16(u16),
    I16(i16),
    U32(u32),
    I32(i32),
    U64(u64),
    I64(i64),
}

struct NestedData {
    a: u16,
    b: i32,
}

#[derive(GetItem)]
struct Data {
    a: i32,
    b: u64,
    c: NestedData,
}

let data = Data {
        a: 42,
        b: 1000,
        c: NestedData { a: 500, b: -2 },
};

assert_eq!(data.get(0).unwrap(), Item::I32(42));
assert_eq!(data.get(1).unwrap(), Item::U64(1000));
assert_eq!(data.get(2).unwrap(), Item::U16(500));
assert_eq!(data.get(3).unwrap(), Item::I32(-2));
```

For this particular example, I want the macro to expand to the following...

```
impl Data {
    pub fn get(&self, index: u16) -> Result<Item, Error> {
        match index {
            0 => Ok(Item::U16(self.a)),
            1 => Ok(Item::I32(self.b)),
            2 => Ok(Item::I32(self.c.a)),
            3 => Ok(Item::U64(self.c.b)),
            _ => Err(Error::BadIndex),
        }
    }
}
```

I have a working macro for a single layer struct, but I am not sure about how to modify it to support nested structs.  Here is where I am at...

```
use proc_macro2::TokenStream;
use quote::quote;

use syn::{Data, DataStruct, DeriveInput, Fields, Type, TypePath};

pub fn impl_get_item(input: DeriveInput) -> syn::Result<TokenStream> {
    let model_name = input.ident;

    let fields = match input.data {
        Data::Struct(DataStruct {
            fields: Fields::Named(fields),
            ..
        }) => fields.named,
        _ => panic!("The GetItem derive can only be applied to structs"),
    };

    let mut matches = TokenStream::new();
    let mut item_index: u16 = 0;
    for field in fields {
        let item_name = field.ident;
        let item_type = field.ty;
        let ts = match item_type {
            Type::Path(TypePath { path, .. }) if path.is_ident("u8") => {
                quote! {#item_index => Ok(Item::U8(self.#item_name)),}
            }
            Type::Path(TypePath { path, .. }) if path.is_ident("i8") => {
                quote! {#item_index => Ok(Item::I8(self.#item_name)),}
            }
            Type::Path(TypePath { path, .. }) if path.is_ident("u16") => {
                quote! {#item_index => Ok(Item::U16(self.#item_name)),}
            }
            Type::Path(TypePath { path, .. }) if path.is_ident("i16") => {
                quote! {#item_index => Ok(Item::I16(self.#item_name)),}
            }
            Type::Path(TypePath { path, .. }) if path.is_ident("u32") => {
                quote! {#item_index => Ok(Item::U32(self.#item_name)),}
            }
            Type::Path(TypePath { path, .. }) if path.is_ident("i32") => {
                quote! {#item_index => Ok(Item::I32(self.#item_name)),}
            }
            Type::Path(TypePath { path, .. }) if path.is_ident("u64") => {
                quote! {#item_index => Ok(Item::U64(self.#item_name)),}
            }
            Type::Path(TypePath { path, .. }) if path.is_ident("i64") => {
                quote! {#item_index => Ok(Item::I64(self.#item_name)),}
            }
            _ => panic!("{:?} uses unsupported type {:?}", item_name, item_type),
        };
        matches.extend(ts);
        item_index += 1;
    }

    let output = quote! {
        #[automatically_derived]
        impl #model_name {
            pub fn get(&self, index: u16) -> Result<Item, Error> {
                match index {
                    #matches
                    _ => Err(Error::BadIndex),
                }
            }
        }
    };

    Ok(output)
}
```

Comment: Macros can only see tokens, meaning if the derive macro is on `Data`, it doesn't know how `NestedData` is defined. It only gets the name. You should try writing an implementation manually with that in mind before translating it into a macro.

Comment: @kmdreko, I have written this manually, and I have even written a Python file which is able to auto-generate the necessary traits, but I was hoping the Rust macro system could eliminate the Python dependency.

I didn't know that the derive macro could not see tokens of types that the struct refers to.  This seems like a use case for structural records as discussed here.

https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/nested-struct-declaration/13314

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I'm not going to give a complete answer as my proc-macro skills are non-existant, but I don't think the macro part is tricky once you've got the structure right.**

The way I'd approach this is to define a trait that all the types will use. I'm going to call this `Indexible` which is probably bad. The point of the trait is to provide the `get` function and a count of all fields contained within this object.

```
trait Indexible {
    fn nfields(&self) -> usize;
    fn get(&self, idx:usize) -> Result<Item>;
}
```

I'm using `fn nfields(&self) -> usize` rather than `fn nfields() -> usize` as taking `&self` means I can use this on vectors and slices and probably some other types (It also makes the following code slightly neater).

Next you need to implement this trait for your base types:

```
impl Indexible for u8 {
    fn nfields(&self) -> usize { 1 }
    fn get(&self, idx:usize) -> Result<Item> { Ok(Item::U8(*self)) }
}
...
```

Generating all these is probably a good use for a macro (but the proc macro that you're talking about).

Next, you need to generate these for your desired types: My implementations look like this:

```
impl Indexible for NestedData {
    fn nfields(&self) -> usize {
        self.a.nfields() +
        self.b.nfields()
    }
    fn get(&self, idx:usize) -> Result<Item> {
        let idx = idx;
        
        // member a
        if idx < self.a.nfields() {
            return self.a.get(idx)
        }
        let idx = idx - self.a.nfields();
        
        // member b
        if idx < self.b.nfields() {
            return self.b.get(idx)
        }
        Err(())
    }
}

impl Indexible for Data {
    fn nfields(&self) -> usize {
        self.a.nfields() +
        self.b.nfields() +
        self.c.nfields()
    }

    fn get(&self, idx:usize) -> Result<Item> {
        let idx = idx;

        if idx < self.a.nfields() {
            return self.a.get(idx)
        }
        let idx = idx - self.a.nfields();

        if idx < self.b.nfields() {
            return self.b.get(idx)
        }
        let idx = idx - self.b.nfields();
        
        if idx < self.c.nfields() {
            return self.c.get(idx)
        }
        Err(())
    }
}
```

You can see a complete running version [in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9547932c192276aa14041a622bca1c6c).

These look like they can be easily generated by a macro.

If you want slightly better error messages on types that wont work, you should explicitly trea each member as an Indexible like this: `(self.a as Indexible).get(..)`.

It might seem that this is not going to be particularly efficient, but the compiler is able to determine that most of these pieces are constant and inline them. For example, using rust 1.51 with `-C opt-level=3`, the following function

```
pub fn sum(data: &Data) -> usize {
    let mut sum = 0;
    for i in 0..data.nfields() {
        sum += match data.get(i) {
            Err(_) => panic!(),
            Ok(Item::U8(v)) => v as usize,
            Ok(Item::U16(v)) => v as usize,
            Ok(Item::I32(v)) => v as usize,
            Ok(Item::U64(v)) => v as usize,
            _ => panic!(),
        }
    }
    sum
}
```

compiles to just this

```
example::sum:
        movsxd  rax, dword ptr [rdi + 8]
        movsxd  rcx, dword ptr [rdi + 12]
        movzx   edx, word ptr [rdi + 16]
        add     rax, qword ptr [rdi]
        add     rax, rdx
        add     rax, rcx
        ret
```

You can see this in the [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/o8Kvv9fWq)

Comment: Interesting approach, but in my application the nested data structure is going to be quite large (~1k items) running on a micro-controller, so I am a little worried about the run-time hit in this approach.  In the C version of this we have a Python library which generates a data_access.c file which contains an array of structs, where each struct contains a pointer to the data and the sizeof() the data in the pointer.  I want the macro to be able to generate a large match statement to allow the compiler to generate a jump table with similar efficiencies.

Comment: @Darko I _think_ you'll get something like that from the compiler if you remove the `&self` from the `nfields` function.   Calling it is a little uglier though. (Or the compiler might be smart enough to get it without it...) You might want to add the `#[inline(always)]` or `#[inline]` attribute to each `nfields` implementation too to nudge the compiler in the right direction.

Comment: @Darko, it is even better than I suspected. The compiler is able to inline this without issue even for the `(&self)` form of `nfields` and without any inline attributes. I've updated the answer with details.

Comment: I accepted your answer.  I was not expecting the compiler to be that clever, but proof is in the pudding.  I guess when in doubt, let the compiler figure it out.  Well done!